# Accessing Kubernetes services in the cluster from outside of the local network - Bare Metal

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, kubernetes, cluster, bare-metal

I'm running a simple bare-metal multi-master "high availability" enviroment with 2 masters and 2 workers, as well as another VM with HAProxy serving as external Load Balancer.

My question is: it is possible to access the services (dashboard, ngnix, mysql (especially mysql), etc...) from outside of the cluster, exposing them to the network with this setup that i'm running?

I've tried using MetalLB in this enviroment to expose the services as LoadBalancer but it didn't seems to work, and since i'm kinda new to Kubernetes, i couldn't figure out why.

Edit: Got it working now, followed @c4f4t0r suggestion, instead of a external HAProxy Load Balancer, that same VM became a third master node and, as well as the other ones, they now run each one a internal instance of HAProxy and Keepalived, while the VM that used to be the external LB is now an endpoint master for the other ones to join the cluster, with MetalLB running inside the cluster with nginx ingress controller leading the requests to the service that has been requested.

---

### >>> Below are the steps that i've followed to create the enviroment as well as all the configuration used in the setup.

---

#### Set up a Highly Available Kubernetes Cluster using kubeadm

Follow this documentation to set up a highly available Kubernetes cluster using **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**.

This documentation guides you in setting up a cluster with two master nodes, one worker node and a load balancer node using HAProxy.

### Bare-metal Environment

| Role | FQDN | IP | OS | RAM | CPU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Load Balancer | loadbalancer.example.com | 192.168.44.100 | Ubuntu 21.04 | 1G | 1 |
| Master | kmaster1.example.com | 10.84.44.51 | Ubuntu 21.04 | 2G | 2 |
| Master | kmaster2.example.com | 192.168.44.50 | Ubuntu 21.04 | 2G | 2 |
| Worker | kworker1.example.com | 10.84.44.50 | Ubuntu 21.04 | 2G | 2 |
| Worker | kworker2.example.com | 192.168.44.51 | Ubuntu 21.04 | 2G | 2 |

> - Password for the **root** account on all these virtual machines is **kubeadmin**
> - Perform all the commands as root user unless otherwise specified

### Pre-requisites

If you want to try this in a virtualized environment on your workstation

- Virtualbox installed
- Host machine has atleast 8 cores
- Host machine has atleast 8G memory

### Set up load balancer node

###### Install Haproxy

```
apt update && apt install -y haproxy
```

###### Configure haproxy

Append the below lines to **/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg**

```
frontend kubernetes-frontend
    bind 192.168.44.100:6443
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    default_backend kubernetes-backend

backend kubernetes-backend
    mode tcp
    option tcp-check
    balance roundrobin
    server kmaster1 10.84.44.51:6443 check fall 3 rise 2
    server kmaster2 192.168.44.50:6443 check fall 3 rise 2
```

###### Restart haproxy service

```
systemctl restart haproxy
```

### On all kubernetes nodes (kmaster1, kmaster2, kworker1)

###### Disable Firewall

```
ufw disable
```

###### Disable swap

```
swapoff -a; sed -i '/swap/d' /etc/fstab
```

###### Update sysctl settings for Kubernetes networking

```
cat >>/etc/sysctl.d/kubernetes.conf<<EOF
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
EOF
sysctl --system
```

###### Install docker engine

```
{
  apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common
  curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
  add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
  apt update && apt install -y docker-ce containerd.io
}
```

#### Kubernetes Setup

###### Add Apt repository

```
{
  curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
  echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
}
```

###### Install Kubernetes components

```
apt update && apt install -y kubeadm=1.19.2-00 kubelet=1.19.2-00 kubectl=1.19.2-00
```

### On any one of the Kubernetes master node (Eg: kmaster1)

###### Initialize Kubernetes Cluster

```
kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint="192.168.44.100:6443" --upload-certs
```

Copy the commands to join other master nodes and worker nodes.

###### Deploy <del>Calico</del> network (i'm using Weave instead of Calico)

```
kubectl --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf create -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.15/manifests/calico.yaml
```

### Join other nodes to the cluster (kmaster2 & kworker1)

> Use the respective kubeadm join commands you copied from the output of kubeadm init command on the first master.

> IMPORTANT: You also need to pass --apiserver-advertise-address to the join command when you join the other master node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using metalb, I think you don't need to have an external vm with haproxy, you could install an ingress controller in kubernetes and change the service type of the ingress controller to LoadBalancer.

Now You will have an external ip in your lan to access your local service through the ingress controller ip.

```
(Internet) -> (Router) -> Nat -> Metalb-Ip -> Ingress-controller -> k8s-service
```